# how display blog post on webapplication+c#+asp.net

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2005

I am creating a website which needs to have blogs displayed on the page.I dont have any idea on this.I am using .net with c# language and sql server 2005.i m not using MVC architecture.please suggest some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you sit down and work in some detail what you want the page to do, and write it down. Then for each function or action, you work out how that action could be achieved.

Then you can try things and ask specific questions after you've got specific problems. At the moment this request is just 'HELP' and that's not what gets answered here. This is not a training site!

Good luck!